# What is log message `Failed to remove attribute… "Operation not permitted"` during Time Machine backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine, error, logs

When my macOS laptop does Time Machine backups, I see in the log a pattern of error messages reading, `Failed to remove attribute '…' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"`. What causes this set of error messages?  Is it evidence of a problem, or is it just part of the noise macOS makes in the log?  Should I fix something, or just ignore it?

My laptop runs macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra. My Time Machine backs up to a hard drive connected by USB, and to a NAS volume over the network. The error messages look identical for each destination. The message appear in each backup session, it seems.

The log entries read as follows:

```
2020-04-22 06:52:48.047302-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeFSEventStoreUUID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.047717-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeLastFSEventID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.052541-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.052635-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.PreviousSnapshotVolumeUUID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.052710-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.PreviousSnapshotVolumeName' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.052777-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.VolumeBytesUsed' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.052842-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.VolumeIsCaseSensitive' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.052910-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.fstypename' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 06:52:48.052973-0700  localhost backupd[75694]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.VolumeIsEncrypted' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"

2020-04-22 05:34:26.101674-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeFSEventStoreUUID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102066-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeLastFSEventID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102185-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.SnapshotVolumeUUID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102265-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.PreviousSnapshotVolumeUUID' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102339-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.PreviousSnapshotVolumeName' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102474-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.VolumeBytesUsed' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102588-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.VolumeIsCaseSensitive' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102701-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.fstypename' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
2020-04-22 05:34:26.102813-0700  localhost backupd[74191]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Failed to remove attribute 'com.apple.backupd.VolumeIsEncrypted' from 'file:///', error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
```